# php fwrite append not working

Tags: php, append, fwrite

Hello I am trying to make a script that is based on HTML post and basic PHP.

I have 1 input on HTML, and I have this PHP code:

```
<?php echo'h'?>
```

One of my friends said that if I changed the w to an it would create a new line so I changed it and it is still not working.

Basically what I am trying to do is that when they enter the text box any word, it writes that word to the text document, but the second time it won't create a new line, I just want to create a new line.

Here is my full code:

```
<?PHP
    $file_handle = fopen("sample.txt", "r");
    $file_contents = $_POST['f1'];
    fwrite($file_handle, $file_contents);
    fclose($file_handle);
    print "file created and written to";
?>
```

Comment: What `w` are you talking about?

Comment: you didn't post any relevant code

Comment: <?PHP

$file_handle = fopen("sample.txt", "r");
$file_contents = $_POST['f1'];

fwrite($file_handle, $file_contents);
fclose($file_handle);
print "file created and written to";

?>

Comment: sorry i couldnt post it it didnt work

Comment: please don't dump code in comments. Add it to your question as an edit http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39018351/edit - Edit: Never mind, I did it for you.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and read what's in => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: you never created the new line. `w` overwrites, it doesn't "add" a new line.

Comment: You will need to add the new line character after appending the string, like `$file_contents = $_POST['f1'] . "\r\n";`

Comment: and `w` doesn't append, `a` does. [**RT\*M**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Comment: i added your code @SaschaM78 now it is not writing to the txt file

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have tried a and it is still not appending

Comment: most likely because of your POST array being empty, I'll bet.

Comment: you have an answer below now, ask them.

Comment: oh i just fixed the problem thank you guys

Comment: oh.. and the problem was?

Comment: made the r to a and added \r\n to the code thanks!

Comment: it was all in the manual after all ;-) it pays off to read those :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also other seemingly simpler functions by the names: `file_put_contents()` and `file_get_contents()`, which could be used (in your case) to make things a little easier to handle. The Code below shows the use of `file_put_contents()` and it's kin: `file_get_contents()` to accomplish the task.

```
    <?php

        $fileName       = "sample.txt";

        // GET THE TEXT TYPED-IN BY THE USER...         
        // ONLY YOU KNOW THE WAY TO GET THIS VALUE BUT WE CAN ASSUME (FOR NOW)          
        // THAT IT IS COMING FROM THE POST VARIABLE AND HAS THE NAME: input
        $input          = isset($_POST['input']) ? $_POST['input'] : null;

        // FIRST TRY TO SEE IF THE FILE EXIST, OTHERWISE CREATE IT
        // HOWEVER; WITH JUST AN EMPTY CONTENT
        if(!file_exists($fileName)){
            file_put_contents($fileName, "");
        }           

        // DO THE SAVING ONLY IF WE HAVE ANY INPUT (STRING) TO SAVE
        if($input){
            // GET THE CURRENT CONTENTS OF THE FILE...
            $fileContent    = file_get_contents($fileName);

            // ADD THE INPUT TO THE CURRENT CONTENTS OF THE FILE (WITH A NEW LINE)
            $fileContent   .= "\n{$input}";

            // SAVE THE MODIFIED CONTENT BACK AGAIN...
            $bytesSaved     = file_put_contents($fileName, $fileContent);

            // IF THE FILE WAS SUCCESSFULLY WRITTEN... THEN...
            // DISPLAY A MESSAGE TO THAT EFFECT
            if($bytesSaved){
                print "file created and written";
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to add the line that has been posted to a previously stored file? In that case your code would look like this:

```
$file_handle = fopen("sample.txt", "a"); // append to previous contents
$file_contents = $_POST['f1'] . "\r\n";
fwrite($file_handle, $file_contents);
fclose($file_handle);
print "Content has been appended.";
```

More about the different `fopen()` modes can be found [in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), chapter "modes" and more about escape sequences (like `\r\n`) can be found [in the Strings chapter](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).